# Overcoming Type alias '…' references itself

Tags: swift, enums, recursive-type

## Background

I have an enum which, simplified, goes like this:

```
enum Container<T> {
  case a(T)
  case b(T)
  case c
}
```

I want to be able to instantiate this with a few different types for the generic and use `typealias` for that:

```
typealias IntContainer = Container<Int>
typealias FloatContainer = Container<Float>
```

## Problem

So far, this is all fine. However, I also want to create a recursive instance of this:

```
typealias CyclicContainer = Container<CyclicContainer>
```

Swift reports this with a compile error:

> Type alias 'CyclicContainer' references itself

… This error is still reported when I change the `Container` declaration to:

```
indirect enum Container<T>
```

This is a bit annoying, because this *would* be wholesome and compiling Swift:

```
indirect enum CyclicContainer {
  case a(CyclicContainer)
  case b(CyclicContainer)
  case c
}
```

## Workaround 1

There is a work around for this. I can declare, for example:

```
indirect enum CyclicContainer {
   case container(Container<CyclicContainer>)
}
```

… However, this becomes awkward for concise descriptions of a `CyclicContainer` instance:

```
let cyclicContainer: CyclicContainer = .container(.a(.container(.b(.container(.c)))))
```

Instead of just:

```
let cyclicContainer: CyclicContainer = .a(.b(.c))
```

## Workaround 2

I could also simply create a separate enum for the recursive case, as shown earlier:

```
indirect enum CyclicContainer {
    case a(CyclicContainer)
    case b(CyclicContainer)
    case c
}
```

However, I'll need to: create functions to convert between `CyclicContainer` and `Container`; re-implement various member functions that exist on `Container<T>`; and keep the two types in sync in future if I add a new case or change a case name.

This isn't terribly arduous and it's the approach I'm leaning towards. But it seems a shame to have to do this when Swift *can* handle an `indirect enum` completely happily, but not when its induced by instantiation of a generic argument on the enum.

## Question

Is there a better way?

Comment: "I'll need to create bridge functions between the types" What bridge functions? It's not like you can convert a `Container<Int>` to a `CyclicContainer`. It's only the fact that you need to reimplement the methods that's annoying, right?

Comment: Thanks @sweeper, I've rephrased and removed the term. I didn't mean "bridge" in the objective-c / swift bridge sense.

Comment: I didn't mean bridge in the objective-c/swift sense. I meant converting between the types. What types are you trying to convert between?

Comment: @Sweeper The generic here simplified to `Container` is quite a lot more complex. It has functions defined on it (such as `map`) and (probably at some point) other generic functions in the code base that will manipulate it. What I'm getting at is that these would either need to be implemented 2x, or I'd need to way to map between the two kinds of Container. I'll also need to keep the two types "in sync": if I change one, I need to change the other. This isn't impossibly difficult or anything, but it's a pity given Swift can handle indirect enums happily.

Comment: After many minutes of thinking, I don't think there is a better way. Typealiases in Swift don't work the way you think. They are more like `#define` macros in C where the compiler just dumbly replaces one side with the other. As you may know, without a type alias (a "smart" one), `.a(.b(1))` and `.a(.b(.b(1)))` are of unrelated types: `Container<Container<Int>>` and `Container<Container<Container<1>>>`.